# It is better to have various alarms or one? (for different tasks)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have two tasks which must execute in background when app is closed, but the task are different and can be pending to execute in background in different moments.

What would be more correct? To use an alarm with the two tasks or to use two alarms one for each task?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same scenario. I was using Alarm manager to silent the mobile phone for a specified time of the day and then after that specific time is over I need to turn off the silent mode and bring back the normal mode. So, I have created two alarms, and for those two alarms I set the timing of the task for making mobile phone silent for the whole day and set the alarms for making mobile phone normal for the whole day.

You can think like this: two alarms, one for silent and one for bringing back mobile to normal mode.

So, if 1 user has set following timings for silent mode,

1:00 PM to 1:20 PM
1:40 PM to 2:00 PM etc.

What I have done is, I set the timing for alarm that is responsible for starting of silent mode, so at 1:00 PM and 1:40 PM silent alarm will make mobile phone silent and for bringing back to normal mode I set a normal alarm to run at 1:20 PM and 2:00 PM to bring back mobile in normal mode.

So, you need to make 2 alarms for two tasks.